# Google Cloud: MEAN stack hosted in Europe

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, mean-stack

I've tried to deploy a mean stack with the Google developers console, but after the deployment it just says that the location is US. Is it possible in any way to get a MEAN stack hosted by Google Cloud in Europe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, any zones is supported, this option is hidden under the "Advanced Options" section.  If you click to you expand the "Advanced Options" section on the deployment page you'll see the zone setting.

Comment: Thanks alot chrispomeroy!